# Access - DLookup in a table field?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

For this exercise I have two tables.

**Table A**: `Employee Record` and **Table B**: `Timesheet Record`.

`Timesheet Record` tells me which employee has entered how many hours for a job, as well as other unimportant information.

What I need to know is **how much can we bill the client for those hours on that entry?**

---

I have an Hourly Rate set in `Employee Record` - however, I'm not entirely sure how to pull this information across. In a perfect world, I'd simply do a `DLookUp` into a cell (Putting "Hourly Rate" alongside "Hours" in a single entry), which a final calculated cell that would multiply the two.

Alternatively I could do a calculated cell from "Hours" in `Timesheet Record`, multiplied by "Hourly Rate" in the `Employee Record`, but I'm not sure how I would limit the result to the specific employee of record in `Timesheet Record`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

*PS: Using Access 2010.*

Comment: i'm a bit confused, do you want to just multiply the hourly rate * hours and store that somewhere? If so where do you want to store this?

Comment: It would literally be alike to a calculated field in the table, where Field C = Field A * Field B , but obviously with the further complication as above.

Comment: Dlookup is better to use in a form control. in SQL it is more efficient to use [`Group By`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause. and [aggregation functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp), the SQL equivalent to `DLookup`. You need to [`join`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) the tables. `group` the records, and [`sum`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) the hours data for each Employee. It is great exercise, go for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a select query where you *join* TableA.Id on TableB.EmployeeId, *Group By* TableA.Id and TableB.ProjectId, and *sum* TableB.Hours as BillingHours.

This BillingHours you multiply with HourlyRate as BillingAmount.

Comment: Hi Gustav. Unfortunately I'm more excel-based than Access, I've had to jump ship to put together something for my workplace. Would you be able to define the above in more detail? Is it an extra field in the Timesheet Record table, or a new conjoining Query entirely involving both the Timesheet and Employee Record tables?

Comment: It's a new query. If you are that new to Access, do browse for a tutorial as Access is not a spreadsheet.